# Flexbox CSS results in zero-pixel-tall elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

The following HTML file displays nothing, and every element is 0 pixels tall:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
            <div style="flex: 1; display: flex">
                <pre>Hello</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect it to display a `pre`-formatted "Hello" on the page.

If I remove any of the following, the `pre`-formatted "Hello" appears correctly, and the elements change from 0 pixels tall to 10s of pixels tall:

- Any of the `div`s surrounding the `pre`
- Any of the inline styles applied to those divs (`display`, `flex-direction,` flex`)

Converting the `pre` to a `div` makes the "Hello" appear, but the surrounding elements are all still the incorrect height, 0 pixels tall, rather than the expected tens-of-pixels tall.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: i can't reproduce the problem. the pre is 15px tall ( + margins )  , the divs surrounding the pre are 41 px tall ( maybe i didn't understand correctly your question ) . see here https://jsfiddle.net/c0ufpqk7/

Comment: Huh strange that it behaves like that in JSFiddle; when I paste it into a bare HTML file and open it in chrome it looks like this http://imgur.com/a/PCzxj and all the elements have a non-zero width but zero height

Comment: well. i tried also with a bare HTML file + chrome > http://imgur.com/a/KzpvW it still works

Comment: If you are using Internet Explorer 10 or 11, there is a known bug with the flex shorthand. See https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#4-flex-shorthand-declarations-with-unitless-flex-basis-values-are-ignored